# How do you use javascript to detect if a user has multiple monitors?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use javascript to detect if a user has multiple monitors? And additionally if the monitors are "cloned" or in "extended desktop" mode?

Comment: Did you try researching this question before posting it? From what I read it's a pretty straightforward answer of *No*...

Comment: There is no way to determine this using JavaScript. You could make a rough estimate if the width were more than say 2:1 ratio to the height, but it would still be a guess and also would not cover cloned nor minimized windows.

Comment: I did research but I didn't find a straightforward answer of no.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a screen is extended.

```
window.screen.isExtended
```

The only place I can find info on it [is here](https://w3c.github.io/window-placement/#api-screen-isExtended-attribute). I think it is still a draft spec.

Support (17/05/22):

- ✅ Chrome (v101)
- ⛔️ Firefox (v100)
- ⛔️ Safari (v15.4)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's impossible to find that out but you can make an educated guess using the following (untested) code:

```
var dual_monitor = ( (screen.width / screen.height) > 2 )
```

This will test if the (total) monitor width is at least twice as wide as the height, the closest (normal) ratio is 16:9, even this would return false, so If `dual_monitor == true`, it is fairly safe to say that the user has two monitors.

---

P.S  This will only cover situations where the use has side-by-side, non-cloned displays.

Comment: Unfortunately `screen.width` and `screen.height` only return the current monitor width and and height.